# nodejs : How can I fill a global Array containing all objects of a kind?

Tags: arrays, node.js, object, express, pug

Here is my problem :

I have a class Bot. I would like to fill it each time I create an object of this class. An then show it on a jade file. So far I have :

```
//bot.js
var listeBots = [];
exports.listeBots = listeBots;

// Constructeur
function Bot (nom, probavoyager, probatweet, probaretweet, nbhashtag, probalien, probalike, probamention, probaselfmention, visibilite,probaphoto) {
    this.nom = nom;
    this.probavoyager = probavoyager;
    this.probatweet = probatweet;
    this.probaretweet =probaretweet;
    this.nbhashtag = nbhashtag;
    this.probalien = probalien;
    this.probalike = probalike;
    this.probamention = probamention;
    this.probaselfmention = probaselfmention;
    this.visibilite = visibilite;
    this.probaphoto = probaphoto;
}

exports.BotSuiveur = function(name){
    Bot.call(this, name, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 0.05, 0.1 );
    listeBots.push(this);
    //console.log(this);
};

exports.BotLeader = function(name){
    Bot.call(this, name, 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.8, 0.8, 0.2 );
    listeBots.push(this);
    //console.log(this);
};

function BotVoyageur() {
    Bot.call(this, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.8, 0.15, 0.8 );
    //console.log(this);
}

// jade file
each kw in listeBots
            li= kw
```

My jade file just shows me Object[Object] and so on
How can I get the objects value visible in jade ?

Thanks in advance !
Romain

Comment: why you are not iterate over it and show it's values ?

Comment: what do you mean ? I do iterate on it in my jade code

Comment: each kw in listeBots
            li= kw

Comment: can you attach your jade code please ? thanks for your response.

Comment: I did it.Thanks for your help

Comment: ok, what do you need from `kw` object, for example you can use `kw.nom` to get its nom value.

Comment: yeah I tried that and I get an empty string. If I let like that, I have a list of [object Object] items. I feel like my object is not well initialized. Are my constructors well formatted ?

Comment: your constructor is okey but why are not using `new Bot(...)` ?

Comment: I don't really know, is it different ? is it better ? I'm totally new in nodejs!

Comment: It's far better than calling constructor your self and do not use this as a variable in your function, I add better code as answer, please try it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use constructors with `new` keyword and try to not to use `this` keyword in function as a variable.

```
//bot.js
var listeBots = [];
exports.listeBots = listeBots;

// Constructeur
function Bot (nom, probavoyager, probatweet, probaretweet, nbhashtag, probalien, probalike, probamention, probaselfmention, visibilite,probaphoto) {
    this.nom = nom;
    this.probavoyager = probavoyager;
    this.probatweet = probatweet;
    this.probaretweet =probaretweet;
    this.nbhashtag = nbhashtag;
    this.probalien = probalien;
    this.probalike = probalike;
    this.probamention = probamention;
    this.probaselfmention = probaselfmention;
    this.visibilite = visibilite;
    this.probaphoto = probaphoto;
}

exports.BotSuiveur = function(name){
    /* creates bot instance */
    var bot = new Bot(name, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 0.05, 0.1 );
    listeBots.push(bot);
    //console.log(bot);
};

exports.BotLeader = function(name){
    /* creates bot instance */
    var bot = new Bot(name, 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.8, 0.8, 0.2 );
    listeBots.push(bot);
    //console.log(bot);
};

function BotVoyageur() {
    /* creates bot instance */
    var bot = new Bot('name', 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.8, 0.15, 0.8 );
    //console.log(bot);
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, it's pretty much like others languages actually ^^ I'll try this out and let you know if I managed to solve this out.

Comment: Ok It seems to be solved thanks to your explanations and I also removed the "this" argument in my constructor. Thanks ;) I might repost later for other problems ^^